# WebMatrix - error with database ane umbraco

Tags: c#, database, web, umbraco, webmatrix

I have problem with use Umbraco in WebMatrix. I installed Umbraco and want to use but when I try open webside I get the error(it genereate webside which i push in my dropbox):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45759281/Odwo%C5%82anie%20do%20obiektu%20nie%20zosta%C5%82o%20ustawione%20na%20wyst%C4%85pienie%20obiektu.htm

I know that it is problem with data base(Microsoft server CE) but i dont know how i should do. 
Could you help my?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a few folks on the team, and they had a few suggestions.

"So Umbraco has issues with holding onto the database.  One thing you can do though is to take the site offline and restart the app pool as part of your publish.  Unfortunately, this will mean downtime for the site during publish, and you’ll also need to perform a few passes."

Steps to get around this:
1.  Add a file named app_offline.html to the root of your site.  This will prevent people from pinging the site and causing Umbraco to grab the db while you are updating it.
2.  Make a change to your web.config (not sure if this is necessary, but this forces your app pool to restart… which forces it to let go of your sdf file)
3.  Publish everything
4.  Remove the app_offline.html from your site

Hopefully this helps - let us know!